# Will a very slow write on a master DB cause read locking on a read replica DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Will a bulk insert on a master DB (only user is one job that writes to it) that takes 20 seconds cause the read replicas to also get locked for 20 seconds while the change gets propagated to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only locks that get replicated with streaming replication (I guess that's what you are talking about) are `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks, which are taken by `LOCK TABLE`, `DROP`,`TRUNCATE` and similar statements, but also (and that's the most frequent case) by *vacuum truncation* (removing empty blocks at the end of a table).

These locks will block activity on the standby. Everything else will *not* interfere with the activity on the standby.

The activity on the standby is limited to reading, and reads do not conflict with data modification: [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) shows that the `ACCESS SHARE` lock taken by a `SELECT` on the table doesn't conflict with the `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock takes by data modifications, so that latter lock doesn't even have to be replicated. And since `SELECT` doesn't take row locks at all, you can never be blocked that way.

Comment: Yes. I have added something to cover this to the answer.